# How to set eclipse view

Tags: eclipse

I have eclipse INDIGO version for Android development. I don't know how but by mistake eclipse view is changed.I want to restore my eclipse view again as before just help me.I want to set my eclipse view in horizontal way i.e. package view and open classes view should be in column wise like.
Now it looks like:

[image]

Comment: drag the package view to the left of the editor view until eclipse suggests a new left position, and then drop.

Answer (score 0):

Try Window -> Reset Perspective...